# Search and Replace on odd/even numbered lines using g

Tags: search, replace, search-replace

I was looking for ways to search and replace on even/odd numbered lines in vim and I came across some solution on google groups https://groups.google.com/g/comp.editors/c/xk9DMoszgq4.
To search and replace on odd numbered lines:
`:g/^/s/foo/bar/|+t+|-d`

To search and replace on even numbered lines:
`:2,$g/^/s/foo/bar/g|+t+|-d`

The solution works, but i couldnt understand on what it is doing. I know basics about using g to filter out lines for a pattern, then do search and replace on those lines. But I dont get it on what is the code post pipe `|` is doing.

Can anyone help me understand it ? Also point to some documentation if there is any, on what pipe does and how to use it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `global` command marks every line matching a pattern and executes a *list of actions* on them. Each action is separated by the pipe symbol, `|`. In

```
:g/^/s/foo/bar/|+t+|-d
```

the pattern is `^`, so all the lines are marked. Then, three actions are executed on the marked lines:

1. `s/foo/bar/`: substitute "foo" by "bar".
2. `+t+`: Duplicate the next line. Note that the duplicate, which becomes the current line, is not marked.
3. `-d`: Delete the previous line, *which had been marked* by the global command and is a duplicate of the current line.

As you can see, while the global command marks all the lines, the net effect of steps 2 and 3 is to clear the mark of even lines.

For documentation see `:h :g`, `:h :t`, `:h :d` and `:h :bar`.

Note that operation is more efficiently done with Sed, which you can invoke directly from Vim, for even and odd lines respectively:

```
:%!sed 'n;s/foo/bar/'
:%!sed 's/foo/bar/;n'
```